# ¿Cómo modificar una ventana secundaria creada a partir de una función en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

soy nueva en tkinter de python y trato de modificar una ventana secundaria que creo a partir de una función, quiero ponerle otro frame a la ventana secundaria para insertare widgets y etiquetas, pero no se cómo, me algeraría que me pudieran ayudar

````
 ```
            from tkinter import *
        import tkinter.font as tkFont
        from tkinter import messagebox
        
        #Funciones
        def mostrar(imagen,ventana,ancho,largo):      #Muestra las imagenes en la ventana
            fondo=Label(ventana,image=imagen).place(x=ancho,y=largo)
        

       

 def VentanaNueva():            #Crea ventanas secundarias
         raiz.withdraw()
         new2=Toplevel()
         new2.config(bg="black",bd=20,relief="ridge",cursor="hand2")  
         new2.geometry("700x500")
         new2.iconbitmap("engrane.ico")  
         new2.resizable(0,0)  
#Aquí es donde creo la nueva ventana

        def cerrarVentana(ventana):    #Cierra la ventana anterior
            ventana.destroy()
        
        def Validar1(dato1,dato2,dato3,ventanaAbierta):
            if not dato1.get() or not dato2.get() or not dato3.get():  
                messagebox.showwarning("Cuidado","Introduzca los datos solicitados")    
            else:         
                cerrarVentana(ventanaAbierta)  
        
        #Ventana raíz
        raiz=Tk()
        raiz.title("Diseño de Engranes")
        raiz.resizable(0,0)
        raiz.iconbitmap("engrane.ico")
        
        #Variables
        P=DoubleVar()
        Ko=DoubleVar()
        np=DoubleVar()
        ng=DoubleVar()
        
        
        #Imagenes
        fondoengrane=PhotoImage(file="engranesti.png")
        flecha=PhotoImage(file="flecha.png")
        tabla1=PhotoImage(file="tabla1.1.png")
        
        #Ventana de bienvenida
        paso=Frame()
        paso.pack(fill="both", expand='true')
        paso.config(bg="white")
        paso.config(width="700",height="500")
        paso.config(bd=20)
        paso.config(relief="ridge")
        paso.config(cursor="hand2")
        mostrar(fondoengrane,paso,220,50)
        titulo=Label(paso, text="Diseño de engranes de forma automática", bg="pink", 
            fg="black",font=("Comic Sans MS",14)).place(x=135,y=0)
        m0=Label(paso,text="Introduzca los siguientes datos:",bg="white",
            fg="black",font=("Comic Sans MS",12)).place(x=30,y=270)
        m1=Label(paso,text=("Potencia del" "\nmotor (P):"),bg="white",
            fg="black",font=("Comic Sans MS",12)).place(x=20,y=330)
        PM=Entry(paso,bg="pink",textvariable=P, font=("Comic Sans MS",12),justify="center",width="7").place(x=120,y=345)
        m2=Label(paso,text=("Velocidad del" "\npiñon (np):"),bg="white",
            fg="black",font=("Comic Sans MS",12)).place(x=210,y=330)
        NP=Entry(paso,bg="pink",textvariable=np, font=("Comic Sans MS",12),justify="center",width="7").place(x=320,y=345)
        m3=Label(paso,text=("Velocidad de " "\nla máquina (np):"),bg="white",
            fg="black",font=("Comic Sans MS",12)).place(x=410,y=330)
        NG=Entry(paso,bg="pink",textvariable=ng, font=("Comic Sans MS",12),justify="center",width="7").place(x=535,y=345)
        B1=Button(paso,image=flecha,height=50,width=50, bg="white",
            command=lambda:[Validar1(P,np,ng,paso)]).place(x=600,y=400)
````

> #Ventana No.2
>
> Aquí es donde quiero poner el frame y su configuración

raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Es dificil manejar ventanas tipo TopLevel en un script de tkinter. Como en el comentario anterior, en mejor hacerlo con clases.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
         self.master = master

root = tk.Tk()
app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Con eso tendrás una ventana de tkinter en clases que tendrás que completar. Agrega un botón para abrir una nueva ventana en la clase `MainWindow`:

```
self.btn = tk.Button(self.master, text="Other Window", 
                     command=self.open_other_window)
self.btn.pack(padx=25, pady=25)
```

Así le das click al botón "Other Window" llamará al método `open_other_window` por lo que habrá que definirlo dentro de la misma clase:

```
def open_other_window(self):
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    app = OtherWindow(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Este método instanciará una nueva ventana clase tk.Toplevel que se pondrá sobre al ventana tk.Tk. Lo unico ahora que necesitas es la clase `OtherWindow` con el diseño de la ventana secundaria. Este será igual que ``MainWindow` (de hecho es una copia donde solo el título es diferente):

```
class OtherWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Other Window")
```

Ahora es cuestión de que diseñes tanto la ventana principal en la clase `MainWindow` como la ventana secundaria en la clase `OtherWindow`.